# Is using cross-correlation with a reference wavelet a good approach for vibration detection?

Tags: wavelet, signal-detection

This is my first time actually applying signal processing to a real problem.

I'm trying to monitor some equipment for vibrations. The vibrations aren't constant but occur at some point in time - I've read that wavelets are a better choice for this rather than a simple threshold or performing an FFT; thus the choice to attempt to detect vibrations ("extract the feature") by cross-correlating an incoming signal with a wavelet that's based on a typical vibration pattern.

The issue is that it seemed to work well in the lab with known signals (from which the wavelet was constructed), but testing it on other equipment with the same problem, it's not flagging obvious transient vibrations. I'm not sure if my scaling is off or what, but this makes me think - is that a fair approach in the first place?

Are there other, possibly more tested or valid approaches to this issue or it's just a bit of trial and error?

Comment: Isn't a simple measure such as a sliding variance enough ? From your attempts, "wavelets are a better choice" does not seem to be a universal truth. Never believe in "better than" claims.

Comment: Could you post three typical but different waveforms showing the occurrence of vibrations ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for your comments! That could be something I can try. I'll be able to post a few waveforms next week, if you don't mind :)